# Oauth initiate failing in Magento 1 site

Tags: c#, oauth, magento-1.9

I am using Nick Vane's Magento REST API and the Oauth authentication works on one client and fails on another.

I have tried resetting the consumer information, client key and secret but on the second site still fails.

```
var client = new MagentoApi();

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

try
{
    if (AdminURLPart.Length > 0)
    {
        client.SetCustomAdminUrlPart(AdminURLPart);
    }

    client.Initialize(URL, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
    client.AuthenticateAdmin(MagentoUser, MagentoPassword);

}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    BCCUtils.Logger("Authentication Error: " + e1.Message, true, CurrentModule);
    return -1;
}
```

There was a problem with oauth at 'https://www.xxxxz.com/oauth/initiate' for consumer key 'xxxxxxx'. Message: 'oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key'

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to the community that we resolved this problem by removing "www." from the URL being used within the application.  Once we did that, the MagentoAPI authentication function within the Nick Vane project worked correctly. This was the case only for the one client where we were having difficulty authenticating.